# Cannot see Swift variable contents using AppCode

Tags: swift, debugging, appcode

I'm using Appcode-EAP 3.2, but I've also tried this with Appcode 3.1.7.

When stopped in the debugger, I can see the local variables,

e.g.

```
fromJSON = []
self = []
```

However, if I move one of these to the Watches window to examine its contents, I get this:

`self = Cannot evaluate expression for language Swift`

I can't believe it isn't possible to see the values of a variable or property. Can anyone guide me as to what I'm failing to do?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question for the Appcode people?

Answer (score 1):

Current AppCode versions (stable 3.1 and 3.2 EAP) don't support Swift debugging. It should be included into the final 3.2 release however: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-11626